# How to assign value to the output of eval function in python

Tags: python, eval, evaluation

I tried to assign some value to output of the `eval` function as below:

```
d = {"a": 10}
st1 = 'd'
st2 = '["a"]'
eval(st1 + st2) = 15
```

I got this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I also tried this:

```
x = eval(st1 + st2)
x = 15
```

But it doesn't change the `d` dictionary. I tried to `eval` the whole assignment like this:

```
eval(st1 + st2 + ' = 15')
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1
  d["a"] = 15
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also have tried to use `ast.literal_eval()` function and all the results were the same. So, any idea how to do it??

**EDIT 1:**

For clarification as @LennartRegebro requested for, I should say that I have some dictionaries with some specific key and value pairs. I have a text file which I get from user and some of these values are defined there and I should change basic dictionaries values to these user defined ones. I have parser which parses the text file and for each change, it gives me a tuple containing dictionary name, key and value; all are strings. I wanted to do the assignments by `eval` function, which I understood that I can't.

**EDIT 2:**

As @lejlot suggested, I used `globals()` and added below lines to my code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\["([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]+)"\]')
globals()[st1][pattern.findall(st2)[0]] = 15
```

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but you can't do it with `eval`. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you access your variables through `globals()` (or `locals()`) instead of  `eval`?

```
d={'a':10}
globals()['d']['a']=15
print d['a']
```

in your particular case

```
d={'a':10}
s1='d'
s2='a'
globals()[s1][s2]=15
print d['a']
```

Comment: If I want to use your solution I should write a code like `globals()[eval(s1)]eval(s2)` which gives me a syntax error.

Comment: because you should not use `s2=["a"]` but simply `s2='a'` and `globals()[s1][s2]`, **no** `eval`s

Comment: Actually, it's an input; but I think I can change it somehow. Thank you. I'll let you know about the result.

Comment: I edited my post with the solution using your suggestion in details . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple,

```
exec(st1 + st2 + '= 15')
```

`eval` won't work. Use exec instead. That too assignment should be done inside within the argument itself.

Though using `exec` is a highly unrecommended practice.

Comment: exec() is (almost) never the correct solution and certainly not the correct solution to a newbie SO question. It *works* yes, but it's not the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, but even what he is trying to achieve is unclear. And to what he desired, I thought to give this hack. I know this is a horrendous practice.

Comment: The you should at least say so in the answer.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, Sushant's answer worked for me, but what is better than this so? Can you give me an alternative?

Comment: I do agree, that this should not be considered as the "solution". exec has its own use, but not in such simple tasks, which can be solved in more simple, safe way.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi: Anything is better than this. I can't give you an alternative as you have not explained the problem. (OK, you explained it in an edit above, I see now). Lejlot's solution is better.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi Sorry, I couldn't figure out your gender from your name. Iranian names are new to me :)

Comment: @SushantGupta, I'm Iranian, but my name is actually arabic.